# GRX crank with Ultegra groupset

Tags: gears, bottom-bracket, compact-crankset

I currently ride a full Ultegra di2 setup with 50/34 chainrings and 11/32 11sp rear cassette.  I would like to run the GRX 46/30 chainrings because 50/11 gearing is a waste for me.  I could either stay with the 11/32 and get a lower gear or move to 11/28 and get tighter spacing.  Both my crank and the GRX are Hollowtech II, but I note the chainline on GRX is 46.9 mm while the chainline on my FC-R8000 is 43.5.  Is the chainline set by the crank or the bottom bracket?  If it is set by the crank, it this enough to matter?  Will a GRX crank work on the bottom bracket I have?

Answer (score 4):

It's set by the crank, and is like this because GRX is targeted at 135mm/142mm rear ends. GRX takes the same BB as any HT2 road crank.

It's enough to matter, but chainstay length is the other piece of how much it matters. Doing this kind of thing on super short chainstay bikes can yield pretty compromised results in terms of number of rough combinations, and at the other extreme may not be such a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

The [Shimano compatibility charts](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455) say that GRX FC-RX800/600 cranks are only compatible with the FD-RX800 front derailleur. I suspect that is because of the shape of the cage for smaller rings and the reach to accommodate the wider chainline of the cranks.

It's a mystery to me why Shimano does not make sub-compact cranks in their Ultegra or 105 lines. There is a 48-34 Tiagra crank but you are not getting a smaller inner ring.

An alternative is a sub-compact crank from FSA, Praxis Works etc.

Comment: Shimano might not be offering sub-compact road cranks because SRAM effectively doesn’t have them, and Campagnolo only has them in one length for its 12s Chorus group. Basically, I think the entire industry hasn’t woken up to the demand yet. I agree they *should* wake up. NB: SRAM AXS groups have smaller chainrings, but they also have smaller cassette cogs in the rear, producing similar effective gearing to standard road compacts. You can run road AXS shifters with the 10-50 Eagle MTB cassette, but I believe you can only do so in a 1x configuration.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Shimano’s attitude seems to be that riders should have capability to match group set level, in reality less capable riders are willing to pay for the reduced mass and better shifting/braking performance of the upper groups.

Comment: Supercompact chainrings also require smaller BCDs, and component makers may be trying to limit the number of SKUs.

Comment: @AdamRice True, but for a manufacturer like Shimano that makes something like 40 distinct groupsets that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The chainline for the GRX groups is very slightly wider than Shimano's standard road groups. This means that the midpoint between a set of double chainrings is 2.5mm further outwards on the GRX groups than on the road groups.

Nathan correctly notes that this is a property of the GRX crankset, not the BB. The curvature of the front derailer cage aside, the issue is that front derailers can only move the cage so far outboard. Thus, it is possible that a road front derailer won't be able to move as far outboard as it needs to on a GRX crank.

I say "possible" because Shimano's compatibility specifications tend to be conservative. Some forum users have actually mounted GRX cranks to road FDs. See this [Trainer Road post](https://www.trainerroad.com/forum/t/shimano-grx-and-cross-compatibility/19369) for one user. A couple users reported success on [this Paceline Forum post](https://forums.thepaceline.net/showthread.php?t=241232). I'm unable to properly link the [Riding Gravel forum](https://www.ridinggravel.com/forum/), but I recall seeing a couple of users report success there, but I believe one user may have reported failure.

One issue is that depending on your frame configuration, you may be unable to lower a road FD enough to hit the GRX chainrings. You will need to adjust your limit screws, and it's not guaranteed that you'll have enough outboard adjustment depending on your frame. If you were using mechanical shifting, I bet your front derailer trim would no longer function properly. Because the crank is moved outboard, cross-chaining in the big-big combination will have an even worse chain angle, which should incur higher drivetrain friction and more noise. (I realize that this isn't a recommended combination, but many riders will do this occasionally in the metaphorical heat of battle.)

In contrast to Argenti, I am not sure that the curvature of the front derailer cage is as much of an issue. This was definitely an issue in the past; using a road FD on cyclocross chainrings in the 2000s and early 2010s never seemed to produce great shifting, and Shimano briefly made a line of cyclocross-specific front derailers for 46t outer rings. I *think* that the big 3 manufacturers have been able to redesign front derailer cages to be less sensitive to the chainring size.

If not GRX, then there are alternative cranks that allow you to mount smaller rings. The issue is that right now, sub-compact cranks are a niche market. Rotor's Aldhu cranks are available with a 24mm spindle (i.e. you can mount them in a Shimano BB) and they can take direct mount chainrings down to 32t, but they're expensive. The other manufacturers of sub-compact cranks that I'm aware of all use 30mm spindles, which would require a new BB (examples include Praxis, White Industries, and Easton). All of these are also expensive.

Last, if you're willing to try oval chainrings, Absolute Black makes oval rings for Shimano road cranks that have an effective average gearing of 32t or 30t in the small ring. However, I don't believe there is any clear advantage for the average road cyclist.

Side note: I've heard mountain bikers comment that the oval rings help them maintain traction during steep climbs on loose surfaces. Some gravel cyclists might be in this position also. My read of the literature is that there's no clear evidence in favor of oval rings in terms of other performance gains (e.g. being able to sustain higher power at a lower metabolic cost).

Comment: There are also choices for square taper BB's in the 46/30 setup. IRD and VeloOrange , these are much less pricy that Easton, et al... and you can easily adjust the chainline with appropriate BB. However, this is only an option if you have a threaded BB.